# 7024 event on Windows service shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-service, eventviewer

I am seeing the following event in event viewer:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">7024</EventID> 
<Version>0</Version> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-26T15:38:20.264489900Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>151689</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="716" ThreadID="3976" /> 
<Channel>System</Channel> 
<Computer>***</Computer> 
<Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="param1">Our service name</Data> 
<Data Name="param2">%%1</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Please notice the param1 and param2 values - while the first one is ok, the second one shows %%1 for some reason, and (maybe) thats why the event text states something like that (I replaced the actual service name):

> Our service name service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..

What does %%1 mean and how can I further investigate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm confused as to your question, and using your quoted text, then:

```
<Data Name="param1">Our service name</Data> 
<Data Name="param2">%%1</Data>
```

Those are the parameters that are put into the text of the event.

For instance if it were:

```
<Data Name="param1">ServerFault</Data> 
<Data Name="param2">Google is cooler</Data>
```

Then the event error would read as:

> ServerFault service terminated with service-specific error Google is
>   cooler.

So the param2 value in your case looks to be a variable "%%1" that refers to "Incorrect Function".

You'd need to investigate why that particular service is failing with an Incorrect Function at this point...that's a whole other question based around the actual service/app you are running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't understand what variable is that. Where is it defined and how service manager resolves it?

Comment: I'm tempted to edit to reverse those two parameters.